# Illustrating the LLN (Law of Large Numbers)

Tags: r, probability

I have to illustrate the Law of Large Numbers through simulations in R.
More precisely. 
I would like to illustrate that the cumulative distribution function of the mean,

[image]

converges to the function f given by
f(x) = 0 if x ≤ μ and f(x) = 1 if x > μ.
In my case, I have to use a dice. That is, each X<sub>i</sub> is the uniformly distributed on {1,2,3,4,5,6}, so μ = 3.5.
Using R, I have tried to proceed in the following way:

```
n <- 100
N <- 10000
mu <- 3.5
for(j in 1:N)
{
V[j] <- sum(sample(1:6), n, replace = TRUE);
}
f <- function(x)
{
if (x<=3.5)
{
y <-0
}
else
{
y <- 1
}
y
}
Vf <- Vectorize(f, "x")
```

So my idea was to compare the cumulative distribution function of the mean with the function f using a plot. How can I implement it in R properly. So I have to plot the cumulative distribution function and the function f in one plot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simulate dice-rolls like this

```
set.seed(1)
n.rolls <- 100
dicerolls <- sample(1:6, n.rolls, replace=TRUE)

mean(dicerolls)
```

As for the rest of your question I'm afraid I'd need some further explanation. Maybe you can draw an image of what kind of plot you want?

If this is homework you should tag your question accordingly, and read the info for the tag.
As you can see this site doesn't support MathJax/LaTeX equation mark-up. If you want to include equations you can do it through something like [codecogs](https://www.codecogs.com/latex/eqneditor.php).

Maybe it's something like this you're thinking of?

```
dicerolls <- function(rolls=2, reps=10^4) {
    mean.per.replicate <- replicate(reps, mean(sample(1:6, rolls, replace=TRUE)))
}

set.seed(1)
dice.seq <- c(1:6, 20, 100)

opar <- par(no.readonly=TRUE)
par(mar=c(2, 2.5, 1, 0.1), mfrow=c(length(dice.seq), 2), 
  cex=0.5, mgp=c(1.5, 0.5, 0))

for (i in dice.seq) {

    hist(dicerolls(i), breaks=50, col="darkgrey", 
      xlim=c(1, 6), ylim=c(0, 3), freq=FALSE, main="", xlab="")
    legend("topleft", paste(i, "dice"), bty="n")

    plot(ecdf(dicerolls(i)), xlim=c(1, 6), main="", frame.plot=FALSE)
}

par(opar)
```

[image]

Comment: The kind of plot is not important. It just should be illustrative.
But I would like to keep my way of simulating the dice-rolls. Since I am forced to use that piece of code.

Comment: I can use ecdf in order to plot the cumulative distribution function. But how can I print both functions, f and ecdf, in one plot? Furthermore, it seems, that something is missing in the definition of function f.

Answer (score 0):

Consider a dice rolling experiment and consider the Expected value for this event .E[X] = 1+2+3+4+5+6 / 6

Suppose we perform the experiment of throwing the dice n times , recording the number that is observed each time , let the observations be X1 , X2 , ….Xn.

If we compute say the mean say Xbar = X1 + X2 + …….Xn / n.

if the n is large then , the Xbar should tend to E[X] .

For better understanding , i have a blog where the intuition and mathematical part has been explained and also there is a simulation you can play with and the python code for the same is also available on the website. The following is the link .

https://statisticsexplained.blogspot.com/2020/06/law-of-large-numbers-explained-using.html.

There is a simulation for better understanding and the python code for the same has been attached too .

Comment: The question is how can this be implemented on R. Your answer provides a mathematical perspective behind the question, but does not answer the question of implementing it in R.

Comment: We shouldn’t assume that a person asking a question about R knows how to translate Python to R, let alone ever using Python. Also, it’s better to explain the code in your answer instead of just providing a link - answers like that are frowned upon :) the ideal thing to do would be for you to translate your python code into r code, place it in your answer and explain it in your answer.